# how to edit the response fields in node-soap

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, wsdl, node-soap

I have the following WSDL definition:

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://app.com/app" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:app="http://app.com/app" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   
   <message name="SoapQuery">
      <part name="TransType" type="xsd:string" />
   </message>

   <message name="SoapQueryResult">
      <part name="ResponseCode" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="ResultDesc" type="xsd:string" />
   </message>

   <portType name="SoapQuery_PortType">
      <operation name="SoapQuery">
         <input message="SoapQuery" />
         <output message="SoapQueryResult" />
      </operation>
   </portType>

   <binding name="SoapQuery_Binding" type="SoapQuery_PortType">
      <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
      <operation name="SoapQuery" style="document">
         <soap:operation soapAction="SoapQuery" />
         <soap:input>
            <soap:body namespace="app" use="literal" />
         </soap:input>

         <soap:output>
            <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal" />
         </soap:output>
      </operation>
   </binding>

   <service name="SoapQueryService">
      <documentation>WSDL File for SoapQueryService</documentation>
      <port binding="SoapQuery_Binding" name="SoapQuery_Port">
         <soap:address location="http://localhost:8002/api/request" />
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

and the following handler definition:

```
var SoapQueryService = {
  SoapQueryService: {
    SoapQuery_Port: {
      // This is how to define an asynchronous function.
      SoapQuery: function (args, callback) {
        // do some work
        callback({
          'ResultCode': 0,
          'ResultDesc': "sdfds",
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Currently, when receiving the following request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <app:SoapQuery xmlns:app="http://app.com/app">
            <TransType>11124</TransType>
        </app:SoapQuery>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

it returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:app="http://app.com/app">
  <soap:Body>
    <app:SoapQueryResponse>
      <app:ResultCode>0</app:ResultCode>
      <app:ResultDesc>sdfds</app:ResultDesc>
    </app:SoapQueryResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But I want the response to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:app="http://app.com/app">
  <soap:Body>
    <app:SoapQueryResult> <!-- not - SoapQueryResponse -->
      <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>  <!-- notice there is no `app:` -->
      <ResultDesc>sdfds</ResultDesc> <!-- notice there is no `app:` -->
    </app:SoapQueryResult>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have tried different approaches but none to seem to have effect on the response type. I feel like I am missing something in the WSDL or the handler..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the `RPC` tag in your WSDL definition and change it from

`<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>`

to

`<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />`

because you're using `RPC` as style it's adding `app:` to the output message and the parts, ignoring your `outputName` and replacing it with `SoapQueryResponse` as well. Removing the `RPC` tag will give you this output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:app="http://app.com/app">
  <soap:Body>
    <SoapQueryResult> <!-- notice there is no `app:` -->
      <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>  
      <ResultDesc>sdfds</ResultDesc>
    </SoapQueryResult>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

By default `node-soap` will remove all `targetNamespace` prefix from the message and message parts if is not stylized `RPC`. I have created a pull request [here](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/pull/1176) which will allow users to add optional `targetNamespace` on the output message to be prefixed on the output only not the parts. So with the suggested pull request, you'd add `targetNamespace` to your message

```
 <message name="SoapQueryResult" targetNamespace="app">
      <part name="ResponseCode" type="xsd:string"/>
      <part name="ResultDesc" type="xsd:string" />
 </message>
```

and you'll get your desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:app="http://app.com/app">
  <soap:Body>
    <app:SoapQueryResult>
      <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
      <ResultDesc>sdfds</ResultDesc>
    </app:SoapQueryResult>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: pulled from your repo and it seems to be working fine.. thanks